# Change Data format in R (don't feel like going back to excel)?

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

Need to change my format from:

```
  Lab     Tobacco.Constituent Snus.Avg Snus.StDev HMH.Avg HMH.StDev HGT.Avg
1 labstat    Nicotine [mug/g]    24836        804  2514.0     149.0  5175.0
2 labstat Nornicotine [mug/g]      338          2    70.6       0.8   108.0
3 labstat   Anabasine [mug/g]      106          1     0.0       0.0     0.0
....
```

To:

```
Lab        Tobacco.Constituent Type Avg   St.Dev
labstat    Nicotine [mug/g]    Snus 24836 804
labstat    Nicotine [mug/g]    HMH  804   2514.0
```

......and so on...

Comment: I think you want `tidy::pivot_longer`

Comment: Is this what you need: df %>% pivot_longer(3:4, names_to = "Avg", values_to = "Value")

Comment: Thanks johnjohn - I did need that but wasn't aware how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`:

```r
tidyr::pivot_wider(
  tidyr::pivot_longer(df, cols = 3:7, 
                      names_sep = "\\.", 
                      names_to = c("type", "measure")),
names_from = "measure")
#> # A tibble: 9 x 5
#>   Lab     Tobacco.Constituent type      Avg StDev
#>   <chr>   <chr>               <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 labstat Nicotine [mug/g]    Snus  24836   804  
#> 2 labstat Nicotine [mug/g]    HMH    2514   149  
#> 3 labstat Nicotine [mug/g]    HGT    5175    NA  
#> 4 labstat Nornicotine [mug/g] Snus    338     2  
#> 5 labstat Nornicotine [mug/g] HMH      70.6   0.8
#> 6 labstat Nornicotine [mug/g] HGT     108    NA  
#> 7 labstat Anabasine [mug/g]   Snus    106     1  
#> 8 labstat Anabasine [mug/g]   HMH       0     0  
#> 9 labstat Anabasine [mug/g]   HGT       0    NA
```

---

**Data**

```r
df <- structure(list(Lab = c("labstat", "labstat", "labstat"), 
                     Tobacco.Constituent = c("Nicotine [mug/g]", 
"Nornicotine [mug/g]", "Anabasine [mug/g]"), Snus.Avg = c(24836L, 
338L, 106L), Snus.StDev = c(804L, 2L, 1L), HMH.Avg = c(2514, 
70.6, 0), HMH.StDev = c(149, 0.8, 0), HGT.Avg = c(5175, 108, 
0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))

df
#>       Lab Tobacco.Constituent Snus.Avg Snus.StDev HMH.Avg HMH.StDev HGT.Avg
#> 1 labstat    Nicotine [mug/g]    24836        804  2514.0     149.0    5175
#> 2 labstat Nornicotine [mug/g]      338          2    70.6       0.8     108
#> 3 labstat   Anabasine [mug/g]      106          1     0.0       0.0       0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, Allan Camaron!! Cheers

Comment: I want to appreciate the help provided by all above users in this thread and the stackoverflow community for your assistance in visualization of data in one of my upcoming publications. Kindly contact me if you do not consent to using your user ID in the acknowledgements. Thank you and all the best! Stay safe and healthy!!